# Método com FileUploadEvent de ManagedBean não encontrado: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2, file-upload

Esse é o erro apresentado:

```
ADVERTÊNCIA: Method not found: com.gravar.imagem.ProdutoBean@18154909.upload()
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.gravar.imagem.ProdutoBean@18154909.upload()
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:268)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:238)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

mai 24, 2015 3:30:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ProjetoImagem] threw exception [Method not found: com.gravar.imagem.ProdutoBean@18154909.upload()] with root cause
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.gravar.imagem.ProdutoBean@18154909.upload()
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:268)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:238)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Essa é minha pagina

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Tahoma;
    font-weight: light;
}
</style>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" />

        <p:panel>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Nome:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.produto.nome}" />

                <h:outputText value="Preço:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.produto.preco}" />

                <h:outputText value="Descição da Imgem:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.foto.descricao}" />

                <h:outputText value="Imgem:" />
                <p:fileUpload value="#{produtoBean.file}" mode="simple" />

                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{produtoBean.salvaProduto()}"
                    update=":form:msgs" 
                    actionListener="#{produtoBean.upload()}"  ajax="false"/>

                <p:commandButton value="Limpar" onclick="form.reset()" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>


    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Essa é minha classe Bean

```
package com.gravar.imagem;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUpload;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import com.gravar.imagem.dao.FotoDAO;
import com.gravar.imagem.dao.ProdutoDAO;
import com.gravar.imagem.model.Foto;
import com.gravar.imagem.model.Produto;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ProdutoBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String destination = "C:\\tmp\\";
    private UploadedFile file;

    private List<Produto> produtos;
    private Produto produto = new Produto();
    private Produto produtoSelecionado = new Produto();
    private ProdutoDAO produtoDAO;

    private List<Foto> fotos;
    private Foto foto = new Foto();
    private FotoDAO fotoDAO = new FotoDAO();

    public ProdutoBean() {
        produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
        fotoDAO = new FotoDAO();

        produtos = produtoDAO.listAll();
    }

    public void salvaProduto() {

        try {
            produtoDAO.save(produto);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            produto = new Produto();
            produtos = produtoDAO.listAll();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            "Produto adicionado", "Produto adicionado"));
        }
    }

    public void salvaFoto() {

        try {
            fotoDAO.save(foto);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            foto = new Foto();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            "Foto adicionada", "Foto adicionada"));
        }

    }

    public void TransferFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination
                    + fileName));
            int reader = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) getFile().getSize()];
            while ((reader = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, reader);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        String extValidate;
        if (getFile() != null) {
            String ext = event.getFile().getFileName();
            fotoDAO.save(foto);
            foto.setImagem(ext);
            if (ext != null) {
                    extValidate = ext.substring(ext.indexOf(".") + 1);
                } else {
                    extValidate = "null";
                }


            if (extValidate.equals("jpg") || extValidate.equals("png")) {
                try {
                    TransferFile(getFile().getFileName(), getFile()
                            .getInputstream());
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(FileUpload.class.getName()).log(
                            Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                            "Perigo, erro ao fazer Upload do arquivo"));
                }
                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Sucesso", getFile()
                        .getFileName()
                        + "seu upload. conteudo"
                        + getFile().getContentType()
                        + "tamanho"
                        + getFile().getSize()));

            } else {
                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Perigo",
                        "o arquivo tem que ser pdf"));

            }
        } else {

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    "Perigo, selecione o arquivo"));
        }

    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }

    public void setProdutos(List<Produto> produtos) {
        this.produtos = produtos;
    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public Produto getProdutoSelecionado() {
        return produtoSelecionado;
    }

    public void setProdutoSelecionado(Produto produtoSelecionado) {
        this.produtoSelecionado = produtoSelecionado;
    }

    public ProdutoDAO getProdutoDAO() {
        return produtoDAO;
    }

    public void setProdutoDAO(ProdutoDAO produtoDAO) {
        this.produtoDAO = produtoDAO;
    }

    public List<Foto> getFotos() {
        return fotos;
    }

    public void setFotos(List<Foto> fotos) {
        this.fotos = fotos;
    }

    public Foto getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(Foto foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public FotoDAO getFotoDAO() {
        return fotoDAO;
    }

    public void setFotoDAO(FotoDAO fotoDAO) {
        this.fotoDAO = fotoDAO;
    }

}
```

Comment: O problema é que na **EL** você referenciou o método `upload` sem parâmetros, e no seu bean você só tem um método `upload` com um parâmetro.

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você falou.